# Show that $C([0,1])$ is dense in $L^p_w([0,1])$, for an integrable function $w\ge0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces

> Let $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $w$ be a non-negative integrable function on $[0,1]$. Show that the space of continuous function $C([0,1])$ is dense in $L^p_w([0,1])$ with the following norm
> $$\Vert f \Vert_{L^p_w([0,1])} := \left( \int_0^1 |f(x)|^p w(x) dx \right)^{1/p}$$

My attempt: I am able to show the following

Given any interval $I =[a,b] \subset [0,1]$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists a continuous function $\phi$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\phi \geq \chi_I$ and $\int_0^1 |\phi|^p w dx \leq \int_a^b w dx + \epsilon$.

So, suppose $f \in L^p_w([0,1])$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given then $|f|^p w \in L^1([0,1])$ and non-negative and taking $\mu(dx) = |w(x)| dx$, there exists a continuous $\phi$ on $[0,1]$ so that $\phi \geq 1$ on $[0,1]$ and
$$\int_0^1 |\phi(x)|^p |f(x)|^p w(x) dx \leq \int_0^1 |f(x)|^p w(x) dx + \epsilon $$$$\iff \int_0^1 |\phi|^p |f|^p  d\mu \leq \int_0^1 |f|^p  d \mu + \epsilon.$$
However, I am not sure how to estimate $\int_0^1 |\phi - f|^p  d \mu$ using the above inequality. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: You could probably mimic the proof for the case with $w=\mathrm{Id}$

Comment: @FShrike is there anyway I can use the intermediate result of
$$\forall I = [a,b] \subset [0,1], \epsilon > 0 \implies \exists \phi \in C^0([0,1]), \phi \geq \chi_I, \int_0^1 |\phi|^p w\, dx \leq \int_a^b w \, dx +\epsilon$$

Comment: @L-JS $\Phi$ is really only an approximation of $\chi_I$, so you're unlikely to get anything useful about $f$ from it. In fact, $\Phi\equiv1$ would satisfy your last inequality (when you're taking $[a,b]=[0,1]$). If you're okay with using the density of $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ in the usual $L^p([0,1])$ space, maybe try instead to look at $f\,\mathbf{1}_{w>\varepsilon}$ for some small $\varepsilon>0$.